# How to wait for an http call to get over in js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am making a http call to user using $http. I have a success method which gets called on getting the success response from server. 
My question is how can I wait(i.e not to do what is written after the call till it's done) for http call to get over?

```
main(){ 
    var val = myFunction();
    console.log("---after receiving response---");
    return val;
}
myFunction(){
    var temp;
    fnResource.get(function(data){
        {
            console.log("---on success---");
            temp = data;
        });     
    return temp;   
}
```

In this case, my code prints "---after receiving response---" first and then "---on success---", but I intend to have "---on success---" printed first always.

Update: Have updated the snippet to explain my scenario further.

Comment: The `success` callback is actually what tells you the call was over... Place your code inside it...

Comment: Why you dont do what you have to do inside the `success` callback itself?

Answer (score 1):

Just put the code after the `$http.get(...)` in a separate function and call it from `success` callback.

Answer (score 0):

Your confusion may be stemming from the fact that AJAX calls are *non blocking* (as in *asynchronous*, as in **A** synchronous **J** avascript **A** nd **X** ML).  You can fire off multiple AJAX requests in a row and one will not stop the others from being sent until they are retrieved.  Consider this:

```
$http.get('/route1').success(function() { console.log('route 1 success'); });
$http.get('/route2').success(function() { console.log('route 2 success'); });
$http.get('/route3').success(function() { console.log('route 3 success'); });
```

The AJAX call out to `/route2` and `/route3` do not have to wait for the first AJAX call to complete before they are sent.  Furthermore, in this case, you cannot guarantee what order in which they will return for a number of different reasons all way out of scope for the purposes of this question.  The point is that, running the above code multiple times could result in a log looking like this:

```
route 1 success
route 2 success
route 3 success
```

But it is equally likely that it could look like this:

```
route 2 success
route 1 success
route 3 success
```

And you have no control over it.  You can, however, do something like this to *force* the HTTP requests to return in a certain order:

```
$http.get('/route1').success(function() { 
    $http.get('/route2').success(function() { 
        $http.get('/route3').success(function() { 
            console.log('all requests complete');
        });
    });
});
```

Above the AJAX request to `route1` will block the request to `route2` until it has returned

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `always`

```
myFunction(){
    $http.get("..api/endpoint/").
        success(function(data){
            console.log("---on success---");
        })
        .always(function() {
          console.log("---after receiving response---");
        });
}
```